# Maintaining scroll position after hyperlink postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, hyperlink

I have tried numerious different approaches to my problem, but none of them seem to work out. I basically activate and deactivate users using a asp.net hyperlink and the problem is as soon as you do that, the page scrolls back up because of the postback it creates, so it will be annoying to scroll back down if you have a list of 1000 users. Here is the code iv'e been trying out without success!

```
            // I use this variable for navigating the url for my hyperlink
            var toggleUrl = "AdminListUsers.aspx?column=" + (IsClicked.FirstOrDefault().Key ?? "Name") + "&direc=" + (IsClicked.FirstOrDefault().Value) + "&a=chstat&q=" + id.ToString() + "&d=" + disabled + "&z=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtSearchFor.Text); 

            var hl = new HyperLink(); //These hyperlinks are the same
            hl.Text = status;
            hl.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, (disabled ? "red" : "green"));
            hl.NavigateUrl = toggleUrl;
            hl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "saveScroll(this);return true;");
            cell.Controls.Add(hl);
            tr.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Width = new Unit("10%");

            cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<nobr>"));

            var linkbtn = new HyperLink //These hyperlinks are the same
            {
               //Here as you can see are my attributes for the hyperlink
                NavigateUrl = toggleUrl,
                Width = 16,
                Height = 16,
                CssClass = disabled ? "user-status-disabled" : "user-status-enabled"
            };
            linkbtn.Attributes.Add("id", "aButton_" + id);

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ScrollToADiv", "setTimeout(scrollToDiv, 1);", true); // Not working
            linkbtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.scrollTo(0, location.hash);"); // Not working either

            cell.Controls.Add(linkbtn);
            cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp; "));
```

Comment: P.S. how you **activate** and **deactivate** users, what controls you have used and how post back is performed. Just an advice this is **2017** so encourage yourself and start using **AJAX** Get/Post to fetch/send data from/to server. This way you can avoid unnecessary postback and delay for simple operation.

Comment: It's old code, and there is alot of it so I dont have the time to restructure the entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you could set the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback to true in any of the below three ways.

1. Web.config Level => `pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />`
2. Page Level => `<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>`
3. Code Level => `Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;`

Hope this Helps!!

EDIT
Code help for the comment below (assuming jQuery is being used):

```
$(".user-status-enabled").on("click", function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var scrollPosition = $this.scrollTop();
     $this.attr("href", $this.attr("href") + "&scrollPosition=" + scrollPosition);
});
```

And on the target screen, access this scrollPosition from Query String and set the scroll position on dom Ready

Comment: Yeah I have tried that approach also, it does not work either.

Comment: Looks like you are navigating to a different page on click of the link button and you are registering scroll to div script in this current page.

Comment: I think it's not so good to retain the scroll position in the new screen as we wouldn't be sure that the same data would be retained one the screen. There could be some new data that would be added or existing data could be deleted. I would suggest to revisit the functionality. If not, one thing you could do is to capture the top position (using javascript) on click of the link button and pass that to the target screen by adding a new query string var.